# Getting 02 in response code while firing DE command to HSM

Tags: python, hsm

I am trying to create an offset of an encrypted pin using DE command in HSM (Thales). I am using Python code to do this. After firing the command I am getting 02 in the response. The error codes manual describes it as

```
Key inappropriate length for algorithm
```

I can also see the offset generated in the output. But why this error code is coming in the response. Can I use the offset coming in the output?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I believe you are using latest HSM?

Comment: Yes. Do I need to use separate command?

Comment: The manual describes that when you are using double or triple PVK, the error code 02 will be returned. This is just a warning, it is placed for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

According to reference you can use this offset.

```
If a double or triple length PVK is used, Error Code 02 is returned as a warning but
processing continues generating the offset using TDES in place of DES.
```